# Check Status of Cosmos DB account in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing a PowerShell script that performs several sequential updates to a Cosmos DB account. [There is great documentation on how to do this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-with-powershell#update-account), and the last line mentions this:

> "Check account in Azure portal or using Get-AzCosmosDBAccount for region status."

That function returns [lots of properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/get-azcosmosdbaccount?view=azps-5.9.0#example-1), but none of them are the status that appears in the Portal that shows the account is "Online" or "Updating." Since the update returns before the resource is ready, is there a way that I can check that programmatically in PowerShell so I can wait before performing the next update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you would want to check is `ProvisioningState`.

From the REST API documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-03-15/databaseaccounts/get) (search for `provisioningState` property):

> The status of the Cosmos DB account at the time the operation was
> called. The status can be one of following.
>
> 'Creating' – the Cosmos DB
> account is being created. When an account is in Creating state, only
> properties that are specified as input for the Create Cosmos DB
> account operation are returned.
>
> 'Succeeded' – the Cosmos DB account is
> active for use.
>
> 'Updating' – the Cosmos DB account is being updated.
>
> 'Deleting' – the Cosmos DB account is being deleted.
>
> 'Failed' – the
> Cosmos DB account failed creation.
>
> 'DeletionFailed' – the Cosmos DB
> account deletion failed.

Comment: This was my first thought except that this returned "Succeeded" when I called it from PowerShell but showed "Updating" in the Portal. Is the Portal just behind?

Comment: Yes the portal is usually behind on these updates.